# Проблемы с методом File.isDirectory()

Tags: java

Проблема заключается в том, что в папке есть файлы со следующим названием.

```
Same_name.RTF
Same_name.RTF.p7s
```

И первый файл этот метод считает папкой. Настойчиво и непреклонно.
Как все таки определить папка это или файл?

- Точку искать не предлагайте, там есть папки с ней.
- Первое расширение может быть разным.
- Поиск идет в сетевой папке.

Изначальный вариант:

```
String[] dirList = curentFolder.list((File dir, String name) -> return dir.isDirectory());
```

Comment: покажите как вы проверяете что файл является директорией, пример кода

Comment: А как инициализируются curentFolder?

Comment: а если `java.nio.file.Files.isDirectory( Paths.get( "//host/share/folder/filename" ) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут нет никакой проблемы, вы не правильно используете `filter`.
А именно, если посмотреть `javadoc`, то там написано:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FilenameFilter {
 /**
  * Tests if a specified file should be included in a file list.
  *
  * @param   dir    the directory in which the file was found.
  * @param   name   the name of the file.
  * @return  <code>true</code> if and only if the name should be
  * included in the file list; <code>false</code> otherwise.
  */
  boolean accept(File dir, String name);
}
```

т.е. `dir` это текущая директория, в которой были найдены файлы, естественно ваш фильтр всегда будет возвращать  `true`

А вот пример кода, который должен делать то, что вы хотите

```
List<String> directories =
            Files
                    .list(Paths.get("current_directory"))
                    .filter(Files::isDirectory)
                    .map(Path::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(directories);
```